# CodeBuild and CodePipeline error in (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline

I try to create an AWS CodePipeline that will trigger and pull files from my GITHUB repo whenever there is a commit and then build & deploy to my ECS using CodeBuild.

I managed to create a CodeBuild that takes the files, builds a docker and tag + push it to the ECR and it's working perfectly fine.

BUT - when I try to use this CodeBuild project (**which is working definitely OK manually**) in my CodePipeline I receive an error. `CLIENT_ERROR: AccessDenied: Access Denied status code: 403, request id: MRKXFJDHM0ZJF1F6, host id: C6ds+Gg//r7hxFtBuwwpOPfPPcLbywL5AEWkXixCqfdNbjuFOo4zKEqRx6immShnCNK4VgIyJTs= for primary source and source version arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-805870671912/segev/SourceArti/Qm4QUD8`

I understand it has some connection with the S3 bucket but I can not understand this error. Policies/roles are fine I guess.
Any idea why manually building is working OK and when the pipeline triggers the build I get this error?

Comment: If someone cares, I found a solution which is just giving full S3 access to the role :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the role associated to your CodePipeline has read&write permissions to your artifact S3, which from the error I can tell is `arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-805870671912`

Check the docs about artifacts in CodePipeline:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/welcome-introducing-artifacts.html

Greetings.